# When I data using json in web services its show me following data I want only id and agenda_temp data

Tags: json

when i am fetch a data using json in web services its show me following data i want only id and agenda_temp data

```
{
  "0": "1",
  "1": "Travel Plan",
  "id": "1",
  "agenda_temp": "Travel Plan"
},
{
  "0": "2",
  "1": "New Purchase",
  "id": "2",
  "agenda_temp": "New Purchase"
},
{
  "0": "3",
  "1": "Get together",
  "id": "3",
  "agenda_temp": "Get together"
},
```

Comment: Depends on the programming language you use to process the json you receive. Please add details and/or code.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the Programming languauge, If you are using Java you can use the below code:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(your_JSON_Repsonse);
JSONArray data_Values=data.getJSONArray(Values);
for(int i=0;i<=data_Values.length();i++)
{
 id=data_Values.getString("id");
agenda_temp=data_Values.getString("agenda_temp");

}
```

JSON Values

```
{
  "Values": [
    {
      "0": "1",
      "1": "Travel Plan",
      "id": "1",
      "agenda_temp": "Travel Plan"
    },
    {
      "0": "2",
      "1": "New Purchase",
      "id": "2",
      "agenda_temp": "New Purchase"
    },
    {
      "0": "3",
      "1": "Get together",
      "id": "3",
      "agenda_temp": "Get together"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);

// change the variable name to Values which is clearer.
$Values = $data['Values'];
foreach ($Values as $Value)
{
    echo $Value['id'];
    echo $Value['agenda_temp'];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.